# Python function list parameter variable structure

Tags: python, function, types, parameters, boolean

I'm having trouble using the function below. I'm unable to figure out the `routes` parameter structure.

```
def show_image(data, routes=[]):
    '''
    Given a list of lists of integers "data",
    and an optional list of boolean list of lists "routes",
    show the data as an image and overlay the routes on the image in red.
    '''
    image_data = [x[:] for x in data]
    for i in range(len(image_data)):
        for j in range(len(image_data[i])):
            image_data[i][j] = [image_data[i][j]] * 3
            if any(route[i][j] for route in routes):
                image_data[i][j] = [255, 0, 0]
    io.imshow(np.array(image_data, dtype=np.uint8))
    io.show()
```

I have data parameter working, but I'm unsure about `routes = []`. I know it takes a `"list of boolean list of lists"` which im assuming to be something like this:

```
[[True, True], [False,False]]
```

Can someone give me some dummy `data` parameter to put in to see how it works? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`routes` is expected to be a 3-dimensional list. Each element of `routes` should be a 2-dimensional list that has the same dimensions as `data`.

You can tell this due to the generator

```
route[i][j] for route in routes
```

`route` is one element of `routes`, and you have to be able to access it with 2 indexes. `i` and `j` iterate over the row and column indexes of `image_data` (which is initially a copy of `data`).

For each pixel in `data`, if any of the corresponding elements of `routes` is `True`, it will replace the pixel value with `[255, 0, 0]`.

Here's an example:

```
image =   [[1,     2,     3],     [4,     5,     6],     [7,     8,     9]]
routes = [[[True,  False, True ], [False, False, False], [False, False, True ]],
          [[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, True]]]
show_image(image, routes)
```

`image` is a 3x3 image, `routes` is a list of two `3x3` lists of booleans. I've lined up the corresponding elements vertically. If you read down the column and see any `True` values, that pixel will be replaced with `[255, 0, 0]`, otherwise it will be `[value, value, value]`, where `value` is the value from the original `image` list (e.g. `[2, 2, 2]` for the 2nd pixel in the first row).

Comment: can you give me an example of dummy parameter for data and routes?

Comment: I've added details to the answer.

Comment: exactly what i needed to get things working. thank you @barmar!